# Chrome devtools errors in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, google-chrome-devtools, imageurl

I have two errors with my `rails` application being deployed by `heroku`. The site: https://powerful-atoll-73299.herokuapp.com/. The **first** error is as follows:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://powerful-atoll-73299.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2008/Drawn_wallpapers_Family_tree_007294_.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

I understand this error as it is pretty straight forward. So what I decided to do is to save the image onto my local machine and then put it into my project. So it was no longer trying to pull it's insecure link address. So now I refer to the image as: `background: url("/family-tree.jpg") no-repeat center center scroll;`. This works and has no underlying issues. What happens though, is when I push to `heroku` from my master branch that has the updated change... `heroku` version still keeps the insecure address link to the image. When I inspect the item you can even see that its using `http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2008/Drawn_wallpapers_Family_tree_007294_.jpg` instead of using `/family-tree.jpg`. The picture still shows when I replace the address with the photo location, but the error stays. Any idea to why this is occurring? Why does `heroku` have the address link of the picture when I push the actually local copy up?

**Second** error is as follows:

`'//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.      codeschool devtools.js:1`

I understand that this error is looking for me to replace `@` with `#`. I am not sure where or how to do this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Again, all these errors are currently presenting themselves in production not development.

Comment: Hey, could you use `heroku run bash` and see if the updated file is present?

Comment: If there is could you try restarting your application by `heroku restart`

Comment: @Aflie Alright, so `heroku restart` helped with the second issue. The error no longer displays itself. As for `heroku run bash` I did so and was able to see the `family-tree.jpg` image in the `public` folder and it is being appropriately presented as `background: url("/family-tree.jpg")`

Comment: and still inspecting your app shows the other url?

Comment: Yeah. I have the following in my files `background: url("/family-tree.jpg")` and in `heroku bash`. In the terminal, when inspecting the element I see `background: url(http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2008/Drawn_wallpapers_Family_tree_007294_.jpg)`. IDK why?! -_-

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Issues you might be facing, the assets aren't loaded after the deploy. Maybe a restart could do the trick `heroku restart`

**EDIT**

I went through your css code and it seems you still have that url set as background for your `signup-section` class in your css file.

ref:

```
.signup-section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2008/Drawn_wallpapers_Family_tree_007294_.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover
}
```

Update that and do a deploy, and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is what is weird about the error. Is that on my master branch: https://github.com/Nappstir/my_family/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss I have the correct file. The link to the photo only shows up when visiting the site in production. When I take a look at the files through `heroku run bash`, heroku has the copy of the photo and the photo in the public directory. I have attempted the `heroku restart` which helped with the second error. I still cant find out how its even getting this photo URL. Not in my folders at all.

Comment: I agree, your `master` branch doesn't have that change. But your `modeling-users` branch does. Are you certain that you pushed your master branch to heroku's master branch ?

Comment: Yes, this is most definitely the issue. The fact that I`modeling-users` does not have this change is a problem. I appreciate your help through this.